# Installing Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on SD-Card

Tags: system-installation, acer, aspire

I've been using Ubuntu 12 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 1750, satisfied with the graphics and the performance, I decided that my sluggish an Aspire V5-123 netbook shouldn't be missing out, and yea, I decided to run Xubuntu 14 LTS.

Since the machince doesn't have a CD-reader and my USB Flashdrive is currently missing, what I do have is a micro-sd SDHC adapter and a 4GB microsd. I'd also appreciate it if you can point me to the .iso file and the BIOS settings I need. I have some experience with installing OS (skills that I learned from reinstalling Win7 and installing Ubuntu via CD).

Semi-newbie here.

Comment: An edit (and an upvote as it's now a very good question!)  ;-)  Feel free to edit my answer to make it clearer too!  Just write a good comment so the upper echelons don't disapprove the edit!  **>:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: make a [full back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of both systems before continuing!

Just insert the SD-card into the SD-card reader of your laptop, download [Lubuntu 32-bit](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/lubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso) if less then 1GB of RAM or an old processor or [64 bit](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/lubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) if less then 2GB of RAM or [Xubuntu 64-bit](http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/mirror/cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04/release/xubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) if less then 4GB of RAM or the [64-bit plain vanilla Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) if your netbook has 4GB of RAM.

Then find out from `gparted` what disk the SD-card on your laptop is.  (`sdc` on mine, but yours might differ)

Then just go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and use the following command to copy the iso file to the SD card:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/home/YourUser/Downloads/NameOfIso.iso of=/dev/XdY
```

where: `YourUser` is the name of your user name, `NameOfIso` is the name of the iso file you decided to download, `X` and `Y` are the letters of your SD-Card. (You should have downloaded to iso to the `Downloads` folder!  :P)

***Warning*** `dd` is the abbreviation of **D**isk **D**estroyer!  Ensure twice that the command above is correct before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>!

When you get your prompt back, type `sync` and wait some more.  Then shut down the laptop (no hibernate nor suspend) and only then remove the SD Card!  (I only remember "newbie" and forget all about "semi"  ;-) )

Now insert the SD-card in the netbook, turn it on and boot from the SD-card and follow the official installation instructions for the Ubuntu version you decided to install...

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I made the bootable sd card on my Inspiron 1750 (took me a while to figure that you meant that I had to use an existing ubuntu/linux pc to make a bootable sd). Installation went out smoothly. Thanks :D

Comment: Sorry!  Which part was unclear so I can edit it?  And what did you have to copy?